# How to pass string value in onClick event listener in Javascript as we do it in onclick event listener in html

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

```
render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div
          onClick={() =>
            "FSR.launchFeedback('ax9sgJjdSncZWoES6pew6wMIyCgSXpC')"
          }
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
```

this doesn't work but after this dom gets loaded in the browser and when I add `"FSR.launchFeedback('ax9sgJjdSncZWoES6pew6wMIyCgSXpC')"` as a value in the `onclick` attribute in the similar div, it works.

Comment: Why is it wrapped in quotes? The arrow function is just returning a string.

Comment: because FSR.launchFeedback is not defined by me.It is present in a script that will get loaded after the dom gets loaded

Answer (score 1):

is FSR.launchFeedback is function ? if it is function then you need to write like this

```
onClick={() =>
            FSR.launchFeedback('ax9sgJjdSncZWoES6pew6wMIyCgSXpC')
          }
```

Comment: yes FSR.launchFeedback is a function but this is present in a third part script tag which will be loaded after the dom gets loaded in the browser.If i write the the solution provided by you then it will throw error as FSR not defined

Comment: first load the script then attach the event in dom

Comment: it is giving as FSR is not defined